Construct variable name from function arguments and use it to filter data within the function in Tidyverse R
I have many dataframes (and for this example I show 3 dataframes) that have a similar structure except for a few variables (3 variables that have a different infix).
I would like to create a function that given any of the 3 dataframes and the respective dataframe's infix name e.g., "a", "b" or "c" can reconstruct the unique variable names for the specific dataframe, and then use some of those variables for some downstream processing e.g. filtering the dataframe by the created variables.
My attempt at the desired functions has proven unsuccessful.
The desired result for instance when the function is run as follows should be a dataframe of 233 rows and 5 columns.
check_infix(df_name = df_c, infix_name = "c") # 233 rows x  5 cols

library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.3.2

# Simulate dataset with 1000 rows, 5 columns. The first column "logic1" is a factor column with 2 levels 0 and 1. The second column "logic2" is a factor column with 2 levels 0 and 1. The third column "logic3" is a factor column with 2 levels 0 and 1. The fourth column "cat1" is a factor column with 4 levels 1, 2, 3 and 4. The fifth column "cat2" is a factor column with 3 levels, 1, 2 and 3.
set.seed(123)
df_a <- data.frame(logic_a_1 = factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                 logic_a_2 = factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                 logic_a_3 = factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                 cat1 = factor(sample(1:4, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                 cat2 = factor(sample(1:3, 1000, replace = TRUE)))

df_b <- data.frame(logic_b_1 = factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                   logic_b_2 = factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                   logic_b_3 = factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                   cat1 = factor(sample(1:4, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                   cat2 = factor(sample(1:3, 1000, replace = TRUE)))

df_c <- data.frame(logic_c_1 = factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                   logic_c_2 = factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                   logic_c_3 = factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                   cat1 = factor(sample(1:4, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
                   cat2 = factor(sample(1:3, 1000, replace = TRUE)))

# Create a function that takes a dataframe name, infix_name as inputs. The function checks if the dataframe contains columns with the infix_name .
check_infix <- function(df_name, infix_name){
  infix_name <- {{infix_name}}
  
  logic_xxx_1 = paste0("logic_", infix_name, "_1")
  logic_xxx_2 = paste0("logic_", infix_name, "_2")
  logic_xxx_3 = paste0("logic_", infix_name, "_3")
  
  out1 <- df_name %>% 
    filter(!!logic_xxx_1 == 1, !!logic_xxx_2 == 1 ) 
  
return(out1)
}

# Apply the function to the dataframes
check_infix(df_name = df_c, infix_name = "c")
#> [1] logic_a_1 logic_a_2 logic_a_3 cat1      cat2     
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Created on 2024-06-28 with reprex v2.1.0

That was the problem and it now works. Thanks!
